# Python program stuck when alternating multiprocessing and single processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am getting started with multiprocessing in Python, and I'm trying to compare the difference in the execution time of a task between single and multiprocessing.

The program simply loads a bunch of images, performs a few operations on them and saves them.
I'm doing the same thing, the first time normally and the second time using multiprocessing:

```py
import cv2
import time
import os
import concurrent.futures


def main():

    path = "orig_images/"
    img_paths_list = [f"{path}{img_name}" for img_name in os.listdir(path)]

    ## single processing
    print("Single processing")
    time_start = time.time()
    for img_path in img_paths_list:
        result = process_image(img_path)
        print(result)
    time_end = time.time()
    print(f"Finished in {round(time_end - time_start, 2)} s")


    ## multiprocessing
    print("Multiprocessing")
    time_start = time.time()
    results = []
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = [executor.submit(process_image, img_path) for img_path in img_paths_list]

    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        print(f.result())
    time_end = time.time()
    print(f"Finished in {round(time_end - time_start, 2)} s")


def process_image(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5,5), 0)
    img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(1200,1200))
    img_name = os.path.split(img_path)[1]
    cv2.imwrite(f"mod_images/{img_name}", img)
    result = f"Image {img_name} was processed"
    return(result)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now, I'm getting a weird problem...the task is completed the first time (single processing), but then it gets stuck at the beginning of the multiprocessing part, i.e. at the

```py
print("Multiprocessing")
```

statement. If I switch the two parts, i.e. I run the task by multiprocessing and then normally, it ends without any problems.

I don't get what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I've tried your code and it's working without any problem

Comment: I am not sure why you are hanging; it may be something specific to what `process_image ` is doing. But I can tell you that by having your `as_completed` loop after the `with ... as executor:` block, it will not run until all submitted tasks have completed and is therefore defeating its purpose. That is, it should be moved within the `with` block so you will get results truly as tasks are completed. It's not going to affect the overall timing since you are interested in knowing when *all* tasks have completed, but I am just letting you know you are being inconsistent (... more)

Comment: You might as well just not use `as_completed` and instead `for f in results: print(f.result())`. Also, `results` is poorly named as it is really not the results but a list of `Future` instances. A better name is `futures`.

Comment: Or you can do: `results = executor.map(process_image, img_paths_list)` followed by `for result in results: print(result)`